# Why skin smoothing tool is painting the photo with white color

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, retouching

I don't know photoshop and usually get by by using quick edits in `CaptureOne` but this time wanted to do some basic skin retouch, so downloaded a simple skin retouch tool and following their tutorial right starting from second 00:50 in the video that she starts to paint the blemishes areas, well I do that but it covered it with WHITE color..What is it I am doing wrong?

Tutorial Video Here:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j60oVC0zWvc
```

And here is the white I am talking about and sort of my settings in brush:
[image]

Comment: This is just a guess, partly because you haven't specified the exact tool which may matter. Many retouch tools (starting with the simplest clone tool) require you first to ctrl+click on a (good) region of (something close to) the right colour.

Comment: Yes it looks like you just have the brush tool selected.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a Photoshop glitch, based on your screenshot. You are painting on the mask, or at least you *should* be, since you have the layer mask selected. Photoshop, though, is painting directly on the image rather than on the mask. (However, it may have been the case that you painted directly on the image before selecting the layer mask and taking the screenshot, in which case you already know how to fix the problem.) No software is perfect, and things that shouldn't happen do happen from time to time. All you can do is try again (you may have to relaunch Photoshop so it can find its brain). It's not a problem with the plugin/action.

(To the commenters: the skin smoothing tool/plugin has already been run, and the result is on a separate layer. The area affected in the final image is controlled by a layer mask.)